# How much locked memory does io_uring_setup need?

Tags: linux, io, io-uring

When using `io_uring_queue_init` it calls [io_uring_setup](https://www.mankier.com/2/io_uring_setup). There's an `ENOMEM` returned when there is insufficient amount of locked memory available for the process.

A strace will look something like:

```
[pid 37480] io_uring_setup(2048, {flags=0, sq_thread_cpu=0, sq_thread_idle=0}) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory)
```

What is the formula for how much locked memory is required per entry (first argument)? and if possible, based on the sq_entries/cq_entries in the params structure? [Kernel code](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/io_uring.c#L1140) for the particularly keen. Please don't expand the kernel page size from the formula, as I do want this to be an architecture dependent answer (if it is).

I don't want a dodgy just set ulimit -l to unlimited as an answer. There's this [outstanding feature request](https://github.com/axboe/liburing/issues/246) feature request that would help when implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Jens Axboe the following to [liburing library calls](https://git.kernel.dk/cgit/liburing/commit/?id=ea0fd51b78b3c089add37e8c4ee61abd460beb7a) where added (>=liburing-2.1) returning the size in bytes, 0 if not required, or -errno for errors.

```
ssize_t io_uring_mlock_size(unsigned entries, unsigned flags);
ssize_t io_uring_mlock_size_params(unsigned entries, struct io_uring_params *p);
```